# Turn Off SSL Certificate Verification in Mulesoft 3.8

Tags: ssl-certificate, mule, mule-esb, mulesoft

I am using HTTP connector and using protocol "https". But for the development purpose I wanted to Turn Off the SSL certificate Verification. How to achieve this in Mulesoft 3.8

Answer (score 3):

[[image: check the tab TLS/SSL[1]]

in TLS/SSL tab of HTTP connector, select Custom TLS setting and checked the 'Insecure'

Comment: if you are testing using postman please make sure you disable SSL certificate verification there too. In settings > General > SSL certificate verification.

Comment: But what about for the custom connectors that donot have TLS/SSL tab?